# How to set volume of audio file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, volume

I can't seem to adjust the volume on this audio element i have when loading the page. here is the code

```
    var bleep = new Audio();
    bleep.src = "Projectwebcrow2.mp3";
    bleep.volume = 0.1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the audio tags, just get the DOM Node in Javascript and manipulate the volume property.

```
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
// Getting
console.log(volume); // 1
// Setting
audio.volume = 0.5; // Reduce the Volume by Half
```

The number that you set should be in the range 0.0 to 1.0, where 0.0 is the quietest and 1.0 is the loudest.
Note: If the value you set is not in the range 0.0 to 1.0, then JS will throw an IndexSizeError.

FOR WEB AUDIO API,
A bit of code first, where we’ll load our music file and play it using the Web Audio API.

```
var ctx = new webkitAudioContext();

function loadMusic(url) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', url, true);
  req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  req.onload = function() {
    ctx.decodeAudioData(req.response, playSound);
  };

  req.send();
}

function playSound(buffer) {
  var src = ctx.createBufferSource();
  src.buffer = buffer;
  src.connect(ctx.destination);
  // Play now!
  src.noteOn(0);
}
```

Comment: i got it to work. I had a syntax error. " bleep.volume = 0.1; " it needed to be " bleep.volume = (0.1); " and i used <li><a class="active" href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">Home</a></li> to activate the sound file when you click homepage link in the nav bar

Answer (score 0):

It should work. You need to give us more details(I can't comment). If you didn't already, just add

```
bleep.play()
```

Also, autoplaying audio is disabled by default in most browsers, maybe that is the cause.

Comment: you inadvertently gave me the answer. so i wrote the code as " bleep.volume = 0.1; " it needed to be " bleep.volume = (0.1); ". so thank you lol also i worked around the autoplay disabled by attaching the audio as a beep sound to the home page link with onmousedown play bleep.

Comment: I don't think the parenthesis are necessary.

Comment: the volume adjustment wasn't working without them. when i added them it worked.

Comment: interesting. so it still doesn't work in safari, but it works in chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0):

If your music is an element from the page, you can use:

```
var music = document.getElementById("myMusic");
music.volume = 0.2;
```

If it isn't, use:

```
var music = new Audio('audio/correct.mp3');
music.volume = 0.2;
```

You can check https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp

For more details

Answer (score -1):

Ok..I was going to suggest you create a function for it and call the function. Since it has worked out, best of luck.